# SQL query: extract 1 row from a table A where data in table B is closer

Tags: sql, ms-access

There is 2 tables in **MSAccess** database:

**Table A**

```
idA,data,idB
```

**Table B**

```
idB,idC,data
```

table A join table B through idB

I want extract

```
idA,A.data,A.idB,idC, B.data where B.data>=A.data
```

If I get more than one row

```
idA |A.data         |A.idB|idC  |B.data
1   | 17/04/2016    |1    |2    |19/05/2016
1   | 08/05/2016    |1    |3    |19/05/2016
```

I want select only one row with A.data **closer** to B.data, then

```
1   | 08/05/2016    |1   |3 |19/05/2016
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code might look like this

```
select Top 1 ...
from ...
where B.data<=A.data
Order by datetime difference between B.data and A.data asc
```

Answer (score 1):

For your dataset, it looks like what you want to do is:

1. Subdivide/group your dataset - for any given value of `B.data`, there is a  group of one or more `A.data` values where `A.data<=B.data`.
2. For any group of `A.data` values, you're interested in **only one** `A.data` value from that group: the one that is closest to the `B.data` value for that group.

So, let's consider what we're looking for. Out of a **group** of rows, we are interested in **only one.** This suggests that we're looking for something similar to an aggregate function like `SUM()` or `MAX()`, that takes a group of values, performs a calculation, and returns one value.

The problem with `SUM()` and `MAX()` is that they only let you work with (and return) a single scalar value, but we can add a little complexity using a **correlated subquery**, like so:

```
select B.*, 
(select top 1 A.idA from A where A.data<=B.data order by A.data) as closestA_ID 
from B
```

One potential issue with an approach like this is that if there is more than one A.data value with the same date, you may get *any one* of those values unless you apply additional ordering in your subquery.

Comment: Please, can you write query to test (query with subquery)?

Comment: The example provided (select B.*...from B) should be sufficient to get you going? I tried to use the schema you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Test:

Table A

```
ida data idB

1   19/05/2016  10
```

Table B

```
idB idC data

10  13  08/05/2016

10  51  17/04/2016
```

with

```
select B.*, 
(select top 1 A.idA from A where A.data<=B.data order by A.data) as       
closestA_ID from B
```

I get

```
idB idC data    closestA_ID
10  51  17/04/2016  
10  13  08/05/2016
```

but I search for only a row:

```
idA |A.data         |A.idB|idC  |B.data
1    19/06/2016      10    13    08/05/2016
```

I missed something?